# List of encodeings with URLEncoder encode method

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

```
final String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(urlAsString, "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(encodedURL);
```

I take this code listing from somewhere over net I there is Utf-8 encodeing.
And the explanation for the second parameter of encode method is explained as the "encoding scheme to be used", well what is the list of supported encodings in android , and of course the backward compatibility is the list for supported encoding the same for 2.3 as for 1.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like this instead doing "UTF-8" write `HTTP.` and when you write the dot (.) you'll see other encodings.

Comment: You mean to do a google search with "HTTP." ?, I did not see any list of encodings :(, can you give me so links

Comment: Maybe you havent imported the HTTP...google for HTTP.UTF8. I cant write the import for you, i am from my mobile right now.

Comment: can you tall what exactly should I do ?

Comment: final String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(urlAsString, HTTP.UTF-8);